# Format SQL code: function closed parenthese under the name of function

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I'm working on PhpStorm (the same as for any other IDEA product) and there is a possibility to manage SQL auto-formatting in it.

I'm playing with settings to unify our SQL formatting standard. I've stuck with the closed parenthesis of function and couldn't move by the setting of IDEA. The next example is what I have:

```sql
SELECT person.id,
       JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
               'id', person."PERSON_ID"::TEXT,
               'name', person."PERSON_ID"::TEXT,
           )
...
```

and what I want is

```sql
SELECT person.id,
       JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
           'id', person."PERSON_ID"::TEXT,
           'name', person."PERSON_ID"::TEXT,
       )
...
```

Can somebody advise me something what to do to make it?

I've made changes in all sections already and it couldn't find the necessary setting.

Comment: I prefer what you have before what you want.

Comment: Why use the first one over the second? Being able to read SQL linearly and understand what is part of what without the line indentations changing dramatically is pretty nice. Additionally, SQL formatting is a preference. Rather than enforcing it, why not have a discussion as a team to decide on some formatting best practices and enforcing those during PR?

Comment: @ClearlyClueless First: I'd prefer the second one :). Next: it's much better to auto-format the main piece of work by developers and what couldn't be formatted - would be enforced by PR.

Comment: @jarlh You it's you, me it's me :). In my opinion, it's better to read in a second way. But in any case, it's not question about the best formatting rules, it's about the possibility to format in my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, and we have it reported here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-17350

We'll also add a feature to make more adjustments to the indent placement in the expressions:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-17351

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need to! I will add my variant to all of them. Thank you so much ;)